# What would be an example of a family of 3-connected graphs, all of which have no edge that can be deleted to keep 3-connectivity?

Tags: graph-theory

What would be an example of a family of 3-connected graphs, all of which have no edge that can be deleted to keep 3-connectivity ie. for each graph in the family, G\e is not 3-connected for $\forall$e $\in$ E(G).

Is there a more vigorous way of finding such a family other than drawing a lot of graphs?

Comment: Try starting with the petersen graph, and then generalizing it from an outer 5-cycle to larger ones. Maybe just odds, maybe any size (if you can figure out what the middle section should generalize to)

Comment: Well, you could limit yourself to cubic graphs. That would ensure minimality. Then you just have to worry about the 3-connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, the odd-numbered [generalized Petersen graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Petersen_graph) $G(n,2)$ would probably form a suitable family. Any removal has to disconnect the inner cycle twice or the outer cycle twice plus a link between the two. They are cubic, so removing an edge would immediately reduce connectivity.

Also any generalized Petersen graph where the parameters are coprime would work, ensuring that inner and outer vertices form a cycle (so for example $G(10,3)$).

Shown here is $G(9,2)$.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense - thank you. I did not realize that there was a family of Petersen's graphs as we only looked at the pentagon Petersen's graph during class

Comment: @jseissmann the $G(5,2)$ version is definitely *the* Petersen graph. The rest of the family is more "inspired by" the original. If this answer helped you, please feel free to upvote, and accept $\checkmark$ if it's your preferred answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a graph $\Gamma$ which has $2n$ vertices $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n,w_1,w_2,\ldots w_n\}$ and $3n$ edges $\{(v_i,v_{i+1}),(w_i,w_{i+1}),(v_i,w_i)\,\mid\,i=1,\ldots,n\}$ where $v_{n+1}=v_1$ and $w_{n+1}=w_1$.
This is a cubic  3-connected graph. Removal of any edge leads to a 2-connected graph.